# SQL Query Not Working In Loop

Tags: php, sql, database, loops, insert

I have a script that extracts several rows of data from an external file, I then need to upload each of these rows to a database. I put a query inside my loop but it does nothing. even with error reporting turned on I get nothing. I check the database but nothing is being uploaded.

What is the correct way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
$max_filesize = 100000;
  if($size > $max_filesize) //check file size
  die('File is too large');

if(file_exists($filename)){
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
$str = fread($fp, filesize($filename)); //file text stored in variable
$br = "\n";          //search for new row
$rows = substr_count($str,$br);  //number of rows
echo "Rows: ". $rows."<br />"; 
$row = explode( "\n",$str);

 $x=0;
while($x<=$rows)
  {
  $field = $row[$x]; 
  $exp = explode("|",$field); 

    $case_number = $exp[1];
    $unknown1 = $exp[2];
    $chapter = $exp[3];
    $filed = $exp[8];
    //tons more variables, removed for readability

   $addrow = mysql_query("INSERT INTO records (case_number, wild1, chapter, filed) VALUES('".$case_number."', '".$unknown1."', '".$chapter."', '".$filed."')");
    if($addrow)  
    {  
    echo "<p style=\"font-weight:bold\">Row ".$x." uploaded</p>";   
    }else{
die(mysql_error());
}  

  $x++;
  }
fclose($fp); 
 }
```

Comment: You are not doing any error checking in your query. Add it. The manual shows how. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php The manual will also show you alternatives to the mysql library, which is outdated.

Comment: @Mr.Alien @Pekka, I have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','1');` at the top of my document. I'm getting no errors whatsoever. Nor does the echo at the bottom of the loop display.

Comment: @Gordie use `mysqli_error()` for turning on sql errors, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Mr.Alien, that will not work because he is using mysql_* instead of mysqli_*

Gordie, i advice you step over to using mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* functions, because mysql_* is deprecrated...

Comment: @Mr.Alien Done. I've updated the code. I now get this error: `Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'`. So I check the DB, and there are 19 rows. There should be 43 rows. What would cause the query to stop working? and why aren't my echos echoing the number of rows uploaded?

Comment: can you add en dump of the db???

Comment: Because one of your database field is primary, you cannot insert duplicate value in the primary field, so you are getting this error

Comment: @Mr.Alien It really was as simple as that. I thought the field I set for primary was unique, turns out it's not. Sorry I'm an idiot. Make it an answer and I'll choose it. Free points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned the error `Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'` so you cannot have a duplicate value in the column which is set to `PRIMARY`.